# Transpose of (1,1) tensor

Tags: general-relativity, definition, tensor-calculus, covariance

When we transpose a (1,1) tensor, shall we simply switch the two indices while keeping their upper/lower positions or switch them and also switch their upper/lower positions? In general, would the left/right order matter for a tensor? Is it true that in contracting indices between two tensors, we want the contracted index to be right close to each other?

Answer (score 4):

1. Recall that (1,1) [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) can be identified with linear operators $$\begin{align}A~=~&\sum_{ij} e_i~A^i{}_j~e^{\ast j}\cr
   ~\in~& {\cal L}(V;V)~\cong~V\otimes V^{\ast},\end{align}\tag{1}$$ where $V$ is the underlying vector space.
2. The transposed element is of the form $$
   \begin{align}A^T~=~&\sum_{ij} e^{\ast j}~(A^{T})_j{}^i~e_i\cr
   ~\in~&{\cal L}(V^{\ast};V^{\ast})~\cong~V^{\ast}\otimes V,\end{align}\tag{2}$$ where $V^{\ast}$ is the [dual vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space).
3. If there is only Grassmann-even variables, then the transposed tensor is
   $$   (A^{T})_j{}^i ~:=~ A^i{}_j \tag{3}$$
   in local coordinates.
4. Note that for tensors in [supervector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space) and [supermanifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold), the supertransposition carries additional Grassmann sign factors, see e.g. Ref. 1 for details.

References:

1. Bryce De Witt, *Supermanifolds,* Cambridge Univ. Press, 1992.

Comment: Are you sure the tranpose of a tensor is as (3)? If A is lorentz transformation and B is its inverse, then $B_j{}^i=A^i{}_j$  , which is certainly not A's transpose.

Comment: That seems to be a separate issue caused by raising and lowering indices with the metric tensor, see e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158309/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: A Lorentz matrix satisfies $\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda=\eta$. Or equivalently $\Lambda^T=\eta\Lambda^{-1}\eta^{-1}$. Or equivalently with indices: $\Lambda^{\sigma}{}_{\mu}$$=(\Lambda^T)_{\mu}{}^{\sigma}$$=\eta_{\mu\nu}(\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}{}_{\rho}\eta^{\rho\sigma}$$=(\Lambda^{-1})_{\mu}{}^{\sigma}$. We stress that the last eq. does _not_ imply that $\Lambda^T$ and $\Lambda^{-1}$ are the same matrix, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329885/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: But its transpose and inverse clearly are no the same tensor, just consider a boost in x direction you will see.@Qmechanic♦

Comment: @Qmechanic♦ I know that it has to be wrong but...Why your last equation does not imply that $\Lambda^T=\Lambda^{-1}$

Comment: $\Lambda^T$ is a matrix for a linear map in ${\cal L}(V^{\ast};V^{\ast})$ while $\Lambda^{-1}$ is a matrix for a linear map in ${\cal L}(V;V)$, so they are like apples and oranges.

Comment: I would have guessed it is $(A^T)^{i}_{\;j}=A^{j}_{\;i}$? Because $A^j_{\;i}$ corresponds to a linear map, and thus to a matrix, with j the row index and i the column index. Taking the transpose should give you another linear map. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, another question, why is it ok to write that equation? It seems to me based on the positions of the indices that $(A^T)^i{}_j$ is in $V\otimes V^*$ while $A^i{}_j$ is in $V^*\otimes V$, so we shouldn't be able to write that equation.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, we first need to look up the definition of the transpose. After reformulating your question, it will be very straightforward to answer it.

> **Definition.** Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$ and $A\colon V\to W$ a linear map. Then the transpose of $A$ is the
> linear map $$A^\mathrm{T}\colon W^*\to V^*$$ satisfying
> $A^\mathrm{T}(x)=x\circ A$ for all $x\in W^*$. We also consider the following function:
> \begin{align}
> \Phi\colon L(V,W)&\to L(W^*,V^*)\\
> A&\mapsto A^\mathrm{T}
> \end{align}

We are considering the case where $V$ is $n$-dimensional and $V=W$. Let $\displaystyle{F^{n\times n}}$ be the set of $n\times n$-matrices with entries in $F$. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis of $V$, then the isomorphisms
\begin{align}
\alpha\colon L(V,V)&\to F^{n\times n}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\beta\colon L(V^*,V^*)&\to F^{n\times n}
\end{align}
defined by
$$\alpha(A)_{ij}:=A^i{}_j:=v^i(Av_j)$$
and
$$\beta(B)_{mn}:=B_m{}^n:=v_mBv^n:=(Bv^n)(v_m)$$
allow us to identify tensors/linear maps with matrices. What we can do is ask how the matrix $M$ assigned to $A\in L(V,V)$ is related to the matrix $N$ assigned to $A^\mathrm{T}\in L(V^*,V^*)$.

By unwrapping the definitions, one easily sees that $N$ is the transpose of $M$, i.e. $N_{ij}=M_{ji}$. In other words:
$$(\beta\circ \Phi\circ\alpha^{-1})(M)=M^\mathrm{T}$$