# How do I represent $A$ transpose $A$ in indicial notation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, notation, conventions

I know this question sounds lame, but the book I am following doesn't use the answer I expect and it has been using a similar notations everywhere else which has confused me.

I think Q[Any tensor] transpose Q can be written as **Q**(im)Q(mj), but the book has written **Q**(im)**Q**(jm) which, in my opinion, doesn't even satisfy the condition of matrix multiplication, so it should be wrong.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169762/2451

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(Q\cdot Q)_{ij}=Q_{im}Q_{mj}$

$(Q^T\cdot Q)_{ij}=(Q^T)_{im}Q_{mj}=Q_{mi}Q_{mj}$

where we use that $(Q^T)_{im}=Q_{mi}$

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest is Q times Q, not Q transpose times Q. Check the definition of matrix multiplication.