# Understanding basics of tensors

Tags: tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

I am trying to understand tensors to learn General relativity.
In the book that I am reading they claim that if the basis of a vector space undergoes a linear transformation $T$ then the components of the vector undergo the linear transformation $(T^{-1})^T$ (transpose of inverse of $T$).
This is how they prove it.

> If the initial basis of a vector space is $\{e_i\}_1^n$ and the final basis $\{f_i\}_1^n$ is related by $$f_i=T_i{}^je_j$$ then for an arbitrary vector $v=x^ie_i=y^jf_j$ we have, $$y^k=x^j(T^{-1})_j{}^k=((T^{-1})^T)^k{}_jx^j$$

I am not able to understand the last equality at all.
I believe it is false.
Can somebody clarify if it is correct or wrong?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169762/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Coniferous, have you checked the link Qmechanic suggests? I believe it does answer your question but I'm reluctant to close this as a duplicate unless you agree.

Comment: @JohnRennie I am not able to find answer to my question using the link suggested. What I want to understand is how $x^j(T^{-1})_j^k=((T^{-1})^T)_j^kx^j.$ If i use the concepts of the link given I think I get $x^j(T^{-1})_j^k=((T^{-1})^T)_k^j x^j.$ I am not sure if it is true.

Comment: I've edited the question to make indices not be above each other.  In the process I have in fact changed the order (in the LaTeX) of the indices of the last expression, which I am reasonably sure was your intent in fact.  If it wasn't please revert the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use a notation where I write vectors as $\vec{v}$ (because that's how `\vec` renders and I have no idea how to turn it into boldface in MathJax) and use primes to indicate the different basis: $v'^i$ is the components of $\vec{v}$ in the primed basis (some people use primes on the indices, which I find confusing).

So given some basis $\left\{\vec{e}_i\right\}$ we can write any vector $\vec{v}$ as

$$\vec{v} = v^i\vec{e}_i$$

Now consider a new basis $\left\{\vec{e'}_i\right\}$ which is related to the original basis by some nonsingular transformation matrix $T$:

$$\vec{e'}_j = T_j{}^i\vec{e}_i$$

(Note that this is just matrix multiplication using the ESC, and in particular $T$ is not a tensor.)

Well, we can express $\vec{v}$ in the new basis:

$$
\begin{align}
 \vec{v} &= v'^j\vec{e'}_j\\
         &= v'^jT_j{}^i\vec{e}_i\\
         &= v^i\vec{e}_i
\end{align}
$$

And comparing the second-last and last lines of this we get

$$v^i = v'^jT_j{}^i$$

OK, well we know $T$ is non-singular so there exists a $T^{-1}$, such that, in components

$$T_j{}^i\left(T^{-1}\right)_i{}^k = \delta_j{}^k$$

So let's multiply the expression for $v^i$ above by this on the right:

$$
\begin{align}
 v^i\left(T^{-1}\right)_i{}^k
  &= v'^j T_j{}^i\left(T^{-1}\right)_i{}^k\\
  &= v'^j\delta_j{}^k\\
  &= v'^k
\end{align}
$$

or (big fanfare, and renaming indices gratuitously)

$$v'^i = v^j \left(T^{-1}\right)_j{}^i$$

And finally, we want to make this look like matrix multiplication on the left, so we need to diddle the indices of $T$:

$$v'^i = \left(\left(T^{-1}\right)^T\right)^i{}_j v^j$$

And we're done.

Comment: "I have no idea how to turn it into boldface in MathJax"- \textbf{write here} is the way to write bold

Comment: @Unnikrishnan: sorry, what I meant was I don't know how (in MathJax: I know in LaTeX) to make `\vec{...}` render as boldface.

Comment: \vec{\textbf{write here}}

Comment: What I want is $\mathbf{v}$ instead of $\vec{b}: I don't want the annoying arrow at all (but I want to write `\vec`).  In LaTex I'd write `\renewcommand*\vec[1]{\mathbf{#1}}`.

Comment: @tfb one thing that I still donot understand is how you argue the last step. Let me use $S=T^{-1}$ then what you did in last step is $v^jS_\mathbf{j}^\mathbf{i}=(S^T)_\mathbf{j}^\mathbf{i}v^j.$ Notice that the indices for $S$ didnot change order. you just did transpose and put $v^j$ in the right side. I do not understand how this can be done, because I think it should be $v^jS_\mathbf{j}^\mathbf{i}=(S^T)_\mathbf{i}^\mathbf{j}v^j.$

Comment: @Coniferous The indices did change order!  $v^j S_j{}^i = \left(S^T\right)^i{}_jv^j$: initially I'm summing over the left index, after the transpose over the right one.  Incidentally it's crucial when writing out indices where some are raised and some lowered to keep track of their order, you need to do this in basic LaTeX by `X_i{}^j` for instance (or use a tensor package).