# Why is not ${(\Lambda^T)^\mu}_\nu = {\Lambda_\nu}^\mu$?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

I am following lecture notes on SR. The author writes that the following is equivalent:

$$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda = \eta \iff \eta_{\mu \nu} {\Lambda^\mu}_\rho{\Lambda^\nu}_\sigma = \eta_{\rho \sigma}. \tag{1}$$
This surprises me, because

$$
{(\Lambda^T)^\mu}_\nu = {\Lambda_\nu}^\mu.\tag{2}
$$

And so I expected it to be
$$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda = \eta \iff \eta_{\mu \nu} {\Lambda_\rho}^\mu{\Lambda^\nu}_\sigma = \eta_{\rho \sigma}.\tag{3}$$
Why is this wrong?

Comment: I think you're put an extra flip in there somewhere. Just think about it like matrices: $ABC = D$ means $A_{ij} B_{jk} C_{k\ell} = D_{i\ell}$. Therefore $A^T BC = D$ means $B_{jk} A_{ji} C_{k\ell} = D_{i\ell}$ where I used the commutativity of multiplication, and replaced $A_{ij}$ with $A_{ji}$. This is exactly the same as equation (1).

Comment: The upstairs/downstairs index placement is a red herring that can only add confusion; it's not a 'real' index because $\Lambda$ is not a tensor.

Comment: @knzhou By your first comment, I believe you confirm that you're puzzled too, correct? Flipping the indecies is exactly what I propose, but that's what the lecture notes do not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. OP's three equations should read
   $$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda ~=~ \eta \quad\iff\quad 
   (\Lambda^T)_{\rho}{}^{\mu}~\eta_{\mu \nu}~ \Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\sigma} ~=~ \eta_{\rho \sigma} ,\tag{1'}$$
   $$
   (\Lambda^T)_{\nu}{}^{\mu} ~:=~\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu} ,\tag{2'}
   $$
   $$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda ~=~ \eta \quad\iff\quad 
    \Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\rho}~\eta_{\mu \nu}~ \Lambda^{\nu}{}_{\sigma} ~=~ \eta_{\rho \sigma} .\tag{3'}$$
2. In more detail: Let $V$ be $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with a basis $(e_{\mu})_{\mu=1, \ldots, n}$. Let $V^{\ast}$ be the dual [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) with the dual basis $(e^{\ast \nu})_{\nu=1, \ldots, n}$. Let 
   $$\Lambda~=~e_{\mu}~ \Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}\otimes e^{\ast \nu}~ \in~V\otimes V^{\ast}~\cong~{\cal L}(V;V)$$ 
   be a linear map from $V$ to $V$. Let us call the positions of the indices on $\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}$ for the NW-SE convention, cf. a [compass rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_rose). Let 
   $$\Lambda^T~=~e^{\ast \nu}~ (\Lambda^T)_{\nu}{}^{\mu}\otimes e_{\mu}~\in~V^{\ast}\otimes V~\cong~{\cal L}(V^{\ast};V^{\ast})$$ 
   be the [transposed linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Transpose_of_a_linear_map) from $V^{\ast}$ to $V^{\ast}$. Note that $(\Lambda^T)_{\nu}{}^{\mu}$ is written in the SW-NE convention. Let 
   $$\eta~=~e^{\ast \mu}~\eta_{\mu\nu}\odot e^{\ast \nu}~\in~{\rm Sym}^2V^{\ast}~=~V^{\ast}\odot V^{\ast}$$
   be an (indefinite) metric, i.e. an invertible element in the symmetrized [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). A [(pseudo)orthogonal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) $\Lambda$ satisfies by definition
   $$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda~=~\eta.$$
   See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169762/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Wouldn't you have then an ambiguous notation? Wouldn't you use ${\Lambda_\mu}^\nu$ for refer to both $\Lambda^T$ and $\Lambda^{-1}$?

Comment: @falgenint: Thanks for the feed-back. $\Lambda_{\mu}{}^{\nu}$ does by definition _not_ refer to $(\Lambda^T)_{\mu}{}^{\nu}$ to avoid ambiguity. Rather we use the metric to raise and lower indices, so  by definition $\Lambda_{\mu}{}^{\nu}~:=~\eta_{\mu\rho}~\Lambda^{\rho}{}_{\sigma}~(\eta^{-1})^{\sigma\nu}$, which happens to be equal to $((\Lambda^{-1})^T)_{\mu}{}^{\nu}$ if $\Lambda$ is (pseudo)orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I wanted to say: wouldn't you use ${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu$ for refer to both $\Lambda^T$ and $\Lambda^{-1}$? I mean, if (using (2')) this is correct: ${((\Lambda^{-1})^T)_{\mu}}^{\nu}={(\Lambda^{-1})^\nu}_\mu={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu$ it follows ${((\Lambda^{-1})^T)_\mu}^{\nu}={((\Lambda^{T})^{-1})_\mu}^{\nu}$ and from this you can demonstrate that $\Lambda \Lambda^T=I$ with $I$ the identity matrix. Is this correct?

Comment: The last equation is not correct. When removing indices from a tensor equation, one should re-introduce/put back the metric tensor $\eta$ in pertinent places.

Comment: So I guess I can't say that $(\Lambda^{-1})^T=(\Lambda^T)^{-1}$ although ${((\Lambda^{-1})^T)_\mu}^{\nu}={((\Lambda^{T})^{-1})_\mu}^{\nu}$?

Comment: Yes, you can. Your two equations in your last comment are both correct.

Comment: Then if (from above) $(\Lambda^{-1})^T=(\Lambda^T)^{-1}=\Lambda$, you can apply $\Lambda^T$ in both sides of the last equal sign, and you would have $(\Lambda^T)^{-1} \Lambda^T = \Lambda \Lambda^T$, but the first part is the identity matrix... wouldn't that mean $\Lambda \Lambda^T = I$?

Comment: I answered this in a comment above.

Comment: So, $(\Lambda^T)_{\nu}{}^{\mu}$ has to be written in the SW-NE convention to be consistent with the way the transposed linear map is defined?