# Is the correct way to Lorentz transform a tensor $T$ by writing $\Lambda T \Lambda^T$ or $\Lambda^T T \Lambda$?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

Is the correct way to Lorentz transform a tensor T by writing $\Lambda T \Lambda^T$ or $\Lambda^T T \Lambda$? Is it ${\Lambda_\rho}^\mu{\Lambda_\sigma}^\nu T_{\mu \nu}$ or ${\Lambda^\mu}_\rho{\Lambda^\nu}_\sigma T_{\mu \nu}$? MTW adopts ${\Lambda^\mu}_\rho{\Lambda^\nu}_\sigma T_{\mu \nu}$ on page 439, however some lecture notes (page 5 of http://web.phys.ntnu.no/~mika/week10.pdf) uses ${\Lambda_\rho}^\mu{\Lambda_\sigma}^\nu T_{\mu \nu}$. This makes we worried that I have misunderstood everything with regards to suffix notation. Which of these are correct? Or are both correct? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of convention: Some authors (incl. MTW) use a NW-SE convention on (what they call) a Lorentz matrix $\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}$, while other authors use a SW-NE convention $\Lambda_{\mu}{}^{\nu}$ for (what they call) a Lorentz matrix, cf. a [compass rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_rose). Of course conventions should be applied consistently, and have consequences for other relations in the formalism, such as, e.g., the expressions in OP's title. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329885/2451) related Phys.SE post.