Orthogonality of Lorentz transformation
I know this might be a general or well known topic, but please bear with me, since I have a very specific question regarding this and I want to see specifically whether there is a flaw in my reasoning or logic.
We are using the $(+---)$ metric here.
So basically, we know that
$$\Lambda ^{\mu} \ _{\nu} (\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}\ _{\rho} = \delta^{\mu} \ _{\rho}$$
So that $\Lambda \Lambda^{-1} = 1$.
And we have $$(\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu} \ _{\rho} = (\Lambda)_{\rho} \ ^{\nu}$$
which seems to imply that $\Lambda^{-1} = \Lambda^T$
like an orthogonal transformation.
However, if we plug that in the original equation, we get:
$$\Lambda ^{\mu} \ _{\nu} (\Lambda)_{\rho} \ ^{\nu} = \delta^{\mu} \ _{\rho}$$
which is not matrix multiplication, since the column and row number don't match. This seems to contradict the statement that $$\Lambda \Lambda^{-1} = 1$$
How do I resolve this paradox? Is $\Lambda$ an orthogonal transformation (in Minkowski space) or not?
The indices are confusing me here.

I believe that just follows from the definition of an inverse. It should also follow from the fact that $A \cdot B $ = $ A' \cdot B'$ where the dot is a four vector contraction and the prime is the Lorentz transformed vector.

Good question, +1. I think the issue is changing from tensors to matrices. They aren’t the same thing, and flipping the indices isn’t just a transpose. But I don’t remember the details enough to answer

I thought that a matrix is just a way to represent a tensor. And I thought that flipping indices is actually transposing? Thanks for your comment!

See $:\boldsymbol\S\mathbf A:$ in my answer here : Show that any proper homogeneous Lorentz transformation may be expressed as the product of a boost times a rotation. Equations (A-16),(A-17) provide a proof why $:\Lambda^{-1}\ne\Lambda^{\boldsymbol\top}$.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/567237/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329885/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/456640/2451 and links therein.

The standard transpose operation ${{}\cdot{}}^T$ (which flips a matrix along its diagonal) is equivalent to the Euclidean metric. If you have defined ${{}\cdot{}}^T,$ then you can define the (Euclidean) dot product as $x\cdot y=x^Ty.$ If you instead have just the dot product but not the transpose, you can define the transpose $x^T$ of any vector $x$ as the unique row vector $r$ that has $ry=x\cdot y$ for all $y.$ Because the standard transpose is tied to the Euclidean metric, it has no physical meaning in relativity. In particular, you are wrong to identify ${\Lambda_\rho}^\nu$ as being the transpose $\Lambda^T$ of a Lorentz transform ${\Lambda^\rho}_\nu.$
In relativity, indices are "raised" or "lowered" by applying the metric. To invent a word, the "relativistic transpose" of a vector $x^\mu$ is the covector $x_\mu=\eta_{\mu\nu}x^\nu.$ ($x_\mu$ is the unique covector $r_\mu$ having $r_\mu y^\mu=\eta_{\nu\mu}x^\nu y^\mu$ for all $y^\mu,$ so the situation is just like with the standard transpose and Euclidean metric.) To turn a covector $k_\mu$ into a vector, you instead apply the inverse of the metric like so: $k^\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}k_\nu.$ The process extends to any number of indices: contract the metric against any contravariant index you would like to lower and contract the inverse metric against any covariant index you would like to raise. For the case in your question, ${\Lambda_\rho}^\nu=\eta_{\rho\alpha}\eta^{\nu\beta}{\Lambda^\alpha}_\beta.$
All that said, to answer your question, a Lorentz transform $\Lambda$ is orthogonal under the Minkowski inner product. That is, $\eta_{\mu\nu}{\Lambda^\mu}_\alpha{\Lambda^\nu}_\beta=\delta_{\alpha\beta}=\eta_{\beta\rho}{\delta_\alpha}^\rho=\eta_{\alpha\beta}.$ (Replace $\eta$ with the Euclidean metric and you get the more common definition of orthogonal.) $\Lambda$ will generally not be orthogonal in the usual sense because the usual sense of orthogonal is defined with the wrong metric! (The set of all Lorentz transforms is even called $O(1,3),$ generalizing the notation $O(n)$ used to talk about the set of $n$-by-$n$ orthogonal matrices.)

Wow thank you so much for the detailed answer! In Tong it is mentioned that a tensor is symmetric if $T^{\mu} \  \nu$ = $T{\nu} \  ^\mu$ So if I understand your answer correctly, this does NOT mean that flipping the matrix (as representation of tensor) in its diagonal is equal to itself right? Due to the metric of Minkowski space as you pointed out

Also a related question to this, we do say that the electromagnetic tensor is antisymmetric since $F^{\mu \nu} = - F^{\nu \mu}$, and antisymmetric is then defined in the same way as an ordinary matrix. Because if you look at the matrix representation, it just looks antisymmetric. Is this now possible since both indices are contravariant? (same logic if both indices would be covariant)

@Stallmp Symmetry and antisymmetry only really make sense to me for two (or more) indices that are both (all) up or both (all) down, which is why $F^{\mu\nu}=-F^{\nu\mu}$ makes sense. I can't say I've seen the ${T^\mu}\nu={T\nu}^\mu$ definition. Note that if you insist on treating vectors as columns and covectors as rows, an object like $F_{\mu\nu}$ with two down indices is not really a matrix (a column of rows) but a "row of rows". The 2D grid is just easier to write. The transpose (a column of columns) then does not and can not appear in the definition of (anti)symmetry.

As the invariant scalar product is given by $x^T \!\eta y$ with $\eta= {\rm diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$, a Lorentz transformation matrix $\Lambda$ is characterized by the relation $$\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda=\eta. \tag{1} \label{1}$$ Multiplying \eqref{1} by $\eta^{-1}$ from the left, we find $$\eta^{-1} \Lambda^T \eta \,\Lambda = \eta^{-1} \eta = \mathbb{I}, \tag{2} \label{2}$$ implying $$\Lambda^{-1}= \eta^{-1} \Lambda^T \eta. \tag{3} \label{3}$$ Translating these matrix equations into index notation, we employ the usual conventions $$\Lambda = (\Lambda^\mu_{\;\,\nu}),\quad \eta=(\eta_{\mu \nu}),\quad  \eta^{-1}=(\eta^{\mu \nu}), \tag{4}$$ fixing at the same time also the index positions for all other matrices. Eq. \eqref{1} becomes $$(\Lambda^T)_\mu^{\; \, \rho} \,\eta_{\rho \sigma} \Lambda^\sigma_{\; \, \nu}=\eta_{\mu \nu} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \Lambda^\rho_{\;  \mu}\, \eta_{\rho \sigma} \Lambda^\sigma_{\;\nu} =\eta_{\mu \nu}, \tag{5} \label{5}$$ and eq. \eqref{2} is translated into $$\eta^{\alpha \mu} \Lambda^\rho_{\; \mu}\,\eta_{\rho \sigma} \Lambda^\sigma_{\; \nu} =\eta^{\alpha \mu} \eta_{\mu \nu}=\delta^\alpha_{\; \,\nu}. $$ Finally, the equivalent of eq. \eqref{3} reads $$(\Lambda^{-1})^\alpha_{\; \sigma}=\eta^{\alpha \mu}\Lambda^\rho_{\;\mu }\eta_{\rho \sigma}=:\Lambda_\sigma^{\; \alpha}. \tag{7} $$

Thanks a lot! I was wondering, did you take your equation 1 as an Ansatz/Axiom as a generalization from invariant scalar product in Euclidean space?

@Stallmp A Lorentz transformation is defined as a linear transformation $x^\prime= \Lambda x$ (where $x=(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)^T \in \mathbb{R}^4$ with the property that $y^T \eta x=y^0 x^0-y^1 x^1 -y^2x^2-y^3x^3$ is an invariant, i.e. $(\Lambda y)^T \eta \Lambda x= y^T \Lambda^T \eta \Lambda x= y^T x$ for arbitrary $x, y$. This implies eq. (1).

Thanks a lot again! Just to check, there's a missing lambda in your final term right (in your comment above, not the post)?

@Stallmp Sorry, the last term should read $y^T \eta x$.
