# Index transposing in Einstein notation

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation, covariance

When working with Einstein's summation convention, how do I have to transpose the indexes of the tensor?

For example, suppose I want to take the matrix product with its transpose. Which is the correct one?
$$ (AA^T)^i_{\,j} = a^i_{\,k}a^j_{\, k} \quad  \text{or} \quad (AA^T)^i_{\,j} = a^i_{\,k}a^k_{\,j}.$$

I'm new to this I'm confused.

Comment: It should be$$(AA^T)^i{}_j=A^i{}_k(A^T)^k{}_j=A^i{}_kA_j{}^k.$$Note $^T$ only changes the order of indices, not their heights.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming
   $$\begin{align}A~=~&\sum_{ij} e_i~A^i{}_j~e^{\ast j}\cr
   ~\in~& {\cal L}(V;V)~\cong~V\otimes V^{\ast},\end{align}\tag{1}$$
   is a mixed (1,1) tensor, then the components of the transposed tensor $A^T$ is
   $$(A^T)_j{}^i~:=~A^i{}_j, \tag{2} $$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169762/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. The product $A^2$ of a mixed tensor makes covariant sense:
   $$(A^2)^i{}_k~=~A^i{}_jA^j{}_k.\tag{3}$$
3. OP's product
   $$(AA^T)^{ik}~=~ A^i{}_j  (A^T)_j{}^k
   ~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~A^i{}_j  A^k{}_j \qquad (\leftarrow\text{not covariant!})\tag{4}$$ does not really make sense as a covariant product because there's an implicit sum over 2 lower indices $j$.
4. OP's product $AA^T$ would make covariant sense if there is an implicit (inverse) metric tensor $\eta^{-1}$ to properly raise and lower indices, i.e.
   $$ (A\eta^{-1}A^T)^{i\ell} 
   ~=~ A^i{}_j \eta^{jk} (A^T)_k{}^{\ell}
   ~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~ A^i{}_j \eta^{jk} A^{\ell}{}_k.\tag{5}$$

Answer (score -1):

I would think the second form is the correct one: ${a^{i}}_k{a^k}_j$.

You know that you matrix product is another matrix, i.e. a (1-1) tensor (you have one upper and one lower free index), so this should also show when you represent it as the contraction of the two matrices.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/411537)