# Straighforward source on GR tensor index notation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

I'm very confused by the notation used in General Relativity. For example, how are indices changed for the Lorentz transformation matrix $\Lambda$ with its components $\Lambda_\mu^{\text{ }\nu}$ or $\Lambda_\nu^{\text{ }\mu}$? [Actually, does LaTeX provide embedded means for typing this notation?] Is $(\Lambda_\mu^{\text{ }\nu})^{T}=\Lambda_\nu^{\text{ }\mu}$? Is $(\Lambda_\mu^{\text{ }\nu})^{-1}=\Lambda_{\text{ }\mu}^{\text{}\nu}$?

Can someone please explain (with briefly clarifying why such and such indices are used) how to derive the following?

$$ds^2 = \eta'_{\rho \sigma}\tilde{\Lambda}_{\text{ }\mu}^{\text{}\rho} dx^\mu\tilde{\Lambda}_{\text{ }\nu}^{\text{}\sigma}dx^\nu$$

I would appreciate if someone could please suggest a straightforward source on this notation, since we are not given ones in this course.

Comment: [Related](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[tensor-calculus]+[notation]+ind*): http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158309/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169762/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237270/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255933/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that indices are just a bookkeeping technique for summation, with the added benefit that upper and lower indices indicate how the object transforms under coordinate transformations (i.e.  [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors)). The exact symbol used in the index only matters when it is multiplied by another tensor, which implies summation under the [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_summation_convention). So $\Lambda_\mu^\nu V_\nu = \Lambda_\nu^\mu V_\nu$ only if $\Lambda$ is symmetric.

One way of easily seeing this is by viewing the two-index tensors as matrices. In the first term, $\Lambda_\mu^\nu V_\nu$, you are taking the standard matrix multiplication of a vector, while in the second term, $\Lambda_\nu^\mu V_\nu$ you are essentially taking the transpose matrix multiplication of a vector.

As for your second expression, assuming standard special relativity conventions, is saying the space-time interval, $ds^2 = \eta_{\nu\mu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$, is invariant under [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformations), $\Lambda^\mu_\rho$. This isn't something that can be "derived" from first principles, as Lorentz invariance is usually assumed, [although it can be tested](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5795), most notably by looking for particles moving faster than the speed of light.

Comment: There is also a pretty through answer that addresses some of your questions here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230495/