Four-vector algebra - Notation confusion
I am trying to understand what are the consequences of the ordering (and placement in general) of the subscripts and superscripts for the matrix representation of different elements in four-vector algebra.
We have the following Lorentz transformation: $\Lambda_\mu^{\ \ \nu}$
Is there a difference between: $\Lambda_\mu^{\ \ \nu}$ and $\Lambda_{\ \ \mu}^{\nu}$?
For its transverse we would write: $(\Lambda^{T})_\nu^{\ \ \mu}=\Lambda_\mu^{\ \ \nu}$
What confuses me, and I will refrain from expressing in component notation, is the inverse of $\Lambda_\mu^{\ \ \nu}$ and how it is related to $\Lambda_\mu^{\ \ \nu}$ itself and to the transpose of it?

From Wikipedia's page on Ricci calculus, the rules regarding indices and such in the context of differential geometry: "Ordering of indices is significant, even when of differing variance". So, yes for the first question. For the other, essentially the act of transposing the transformation is equivalent to switching the upper and lower indices.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/567237/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158309/2451 and links therein.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808882
